# What is the appropriate time to visit a grave?

Tags: grave, behavior

As the title says, what is the appropriate time to visit the graves of fellow Muslims? Or is there anything such as an appropriate time? Most men visit after Friday prayer. I ask so, because one day after Isha I wanted to visit the grave of my close relative. But it was dark and I felt I should not visit. It is at that time I had this question.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [fatwa islamweb #193533](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/193533) (in Arabic) there's no appropriate time for that prescribed in any hadith or sunnah collection. But this fatwa quotes that the Prophet (Peace be upon him ) used to visit graves on the nights of ['Aisha's turn](http://sunnah.com/muslim/11/131), some scholars added that this was after Hajat al-wada'. 
So scholars conclude from this that there is no special time or day where one could or should visit graves. Some even went so far that they said it's not allowed to fix a special day or time for this, as this would even be regarded as bida'h, so one should visit graves at anytime without specification, so the only condition for visiting is being able to do so!

There's also no specification on how much time one should spend at a grave!

See also [fatwa islamweb #92718](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/92718/visiting-the-graveyard-on-a-daily-basis) "Visiting the graveyard on a daily basis" in English which is briefly addresses the topic.

Answer (score 1):

As ALLAH S.W.T certainly knows the best. But there is no specific time mentioned to visit graveyard. You can visit any time and perform maghfirah for your nearest deceased. Muslims graveyard is the safest place, so there is no harm in visiting at night.

Comment: @Medi1Saif that was logical though, nothing was such which needed any reference, so my suggestion for you. First read and then comment (; JazakAllah