# Visiting a muslim grave after sundown

Tags: grave

I've seen many different answers so far.
Is it perfectly acceptable to visit the grave after sundown?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that IMHO your inquiry was already addressed in [What is the appropriate timd to visit a grave?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30282/what-is-the-appropriate-time-to-visit-a-grave). To get a better answer you need to added all kinds of relevant information like what's your gender, are you a Muslim yourself or not etc.

Comment: Thank you, I had read those posts prior to my question but they didn't answer what I was looking for. I thank you though. Someone else commented though and gave the answer that helped. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some jurists prohibit visiting the graves at night based on the traditions; They have issued a fatwa against visiting graves at night. On the other hand, it is mentioned in some narrations that some of Imams  went to the cemetery at night . In sum, between these two categories of narrations, it can be concluded that there is nothing wrong with entering a cemetery to  learn from the fate of others, or visiting the graves in public at night, but visiting the graves of specific people is Makruh (it is better not to do). Because the visited grave is deprived of the night party.

It is narrated from Imam Baqir that: Euphrates water originates from the worldly paradise and he said that for God there is a paradise in the west from which the Euphrates water originates and the souls of the believers come out of their graves at sunset and enter that region and enjoy. This narration means that the souls of the believers come out of their graves at the beginning of the night and rest in another place. On the other hand, according to the narrations, the owner of the grave is informed about the visitation of his grave by others, and he becomes intimate with that pilgrim, and his heart does not want to leave his grave, and therefore he is deprived of benefiting from the blessings of the night; Therefore, maybe for this reason, they said that you should not visit the graves at night.

Read more: [YJC](https://www.yjc.news/fa/news/7938941/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%B9%DB%8C-%D8%B4%D8%A8-%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%82%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B4%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF)

Comment: Thank you ever so much for taking the time to explain this for me.